# Display this SQL into MVC View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6.
I've been trying to figure this out using LINQ into a razor view and I'm not getting the results.

How do I get this t-sql

```
SELECT
rt.Name,
COUNT(r.RTypeID)
RTypID
FROM dbo.Request r
JOIN dbo.RType rt
ON r.RTypeID = rt.RTypeID
GROUP BY rt.Name, r.RTypeID
```

that returns these results...

```
Name              RtypeID
Change Request    42
New Request       386
Re-Run            28
other             1
```

Here are the two Models I created
For the rt

```
namespace DBMR.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class RType
    {
        public RType()
        {
            this.Requests = new HashSet<Request>();
            this.RequestInputs = new HashSet<RequestInput>();
        }

        public int? RTypeID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Request Type:")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsSelected { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RequestInput> RequestInputs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

for r

```
namespace DBMR.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class Request
    {
        public int RequestID { get; set; }
        public string JobID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int StatusID { get; set; }
        public int? RTypeID { get; set; }
        public int UrgencyID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public int DTypeID { get; set; }
        public int ResolutionID { get; set; }
        public int AnalystID1 { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public int AnalystID2 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> OpenDT { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CloseDT { get; set; }
        public int AnalystID3 { get; set; }


        public virtual Analyst Analyst { get; set; }
        public virtual Analyst Analyst1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Analyst Analyst2 { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual DType DType { get; set; }
        public virtual Resolution Resolution { get; set; }
        public virtual RType RType { get; set; }
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
        public virtual Urgency Urgency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Just trying to create a page in my MVC app that displays this summary table.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
//Create your context
using(var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    var items = ctx.Requests
        .GroupBy(r => new { r.RType.Name, r.RTypeID })
        .Select(r => new MyRequestData
             {
                 Name = r.RType.Name,
                 Count = r.Count()
             });
    return View(items);
}
```

class to hold the data

```
public class MyRequestData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<table>
   <tr> <th> Heading 1 </th> <th> Heading 2</th> </tr>
   @foreach(var item in Model)
   {
       <tr> <td>@item.Name</td> <td>@item.Count</td></r>
   }
</table>
```

Comment: What about the Controller?

Comment: i've updated my answer to show how you can write your query in Linq and provide it to the view from the controller.

Comment: Where do you factor int he Join? The r.RType.Name and r.RTypeID are pulling from different tables.

Comment: entity framework joins automatically. note how i do `r.RType.Name` instead of having to explicitly join.

Comment: it says 'DBMR.Models.Request' does not contain a definition for 'RType' and no extension method 'RType' accepting a first argument of type 'DBMR.Models.Request' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have a foreign key constraint set up on the `Request` table to the `RType` table? If not, you should set one up and regenerate your data model. With the foreign key set up, entity framework can make this sort of intelligent connection between objects.

Comment: Sure do. Entity Framework works fine using the Foreign Key in other CRUD instances involving Request and RType.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,DBMR.Models.Request>' does not contain a definition for 'RType' and no extension method 'RType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,DBMR.Models.Request>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: whatever anonymous type you created doesn't have `RType`. instead of using an anonymous type, create a class like `MyRequestData` from this answer.

Comment: I was making a mistake on my side. Your solution works perfectly!

Comment: thanks. don't forget to mark the question as the answer by clicking the check mark so if others come across your question they'll know that this was the solution for you. Welcome to StackOverflow!